# Access Rails models inside a different module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, goliath

I'm writing a web service for my Rails app using Goliath and I want to log all the requests sent to my web server. I have this `Api` class which is inside two modules:

```
require 'goliath'

module WebService
  module Rest
    class Api < Goliath::API
      def response(env)
        # Log the request
        Logger.create(id: params['id'], type: params['type'])

        [200, {}, "success"]
    end
  end
end
```

I have a model in `app/models` named `Logger`. The problem is when I run `ruby api.rb -sv` it throws an error:

```
uninitialized constant WebService::Rest::Api::Logger
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: It throws this error because you're runnig this file without rails environment. Open rails console and you'll see it works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the Ruby code with `ruby api.rb -sv` and not via Rails itself (and, thus, the Rails environment is not loading and along with that, your models/ are not loaded).

Run `rails console` from the Terminal (in your app directory) and then run your api code. You should be fine.